# Devolver en la misma consulta campos con el mismo nombre pero de tablas diferentes en LARAVEL

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-blade, querybuilder

Bien, tengo el siguiente problema, enserio espero podáis ayudarme.

Estoy haciendo una consulta con el queryBuilder de Laravel, el problema es que tengo campos de diferentes tablas (Paciente y Medico) con el mismo nombre del atributo y los datos se solapan y no se que hacer.

Esta es la consulta

```
$MisPacientesHoy = DB::table('fichamedica')
    ->join('Medicos','fichamedica.Medico_ID','=','Medicos.ID')
    ->join('Pacientes','fichamedica.Paciente_ID','=','Pacientes.ID')
    ->select('Pacientes.ID','Pacientes.nombre','Pacientes.apellidos','Pacientes.carnet','Pacientes.fechanacimiento','Pacientes.telefono','fichamedica.estado')
    ->where('fichamedica.Medico_ID', '=',$Medico_ID)
    ->where('fichamedica.fecha','=',$fecha_actual)
    ->where('fichamedica.turno','=',$Turno)
    ->orderBy('fichamedica.NroFicha', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

El problema es que necesito que esta consulta, me devuelva tambien los datos de mi medico como ser el nombre, apellido, e ID, pero como ya el paciente tiene la propiedad o atributo llamado 'nombre' al hacer el `@foreach` en mi vista, los datos se solaparan.

```
@foreach ($MisPacientesHoy as $Paciente )

<div>{{ $Paciente->nombre." ".$Paciente->apellidos." ".$Paciente->Medicos->nombre }}</div>
```

Como dije, la consulta esta bien, pero no se como hacer para devolver en la misma consulta datos de tablas diferentes con el mismo atributo

Comment: Podrias darme un ejemplo, por favor y wow, no creí que me responderian tan rapido.

Comment: Ya le entendí, me ayudaste muchisimo. Puedes ponerlo como respuesta para marcarla como correcta <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien, la solución era tan sencilla como usar un `alias` para el nombre de mis campos.

Es sencillo. Al momento de hacer una consulta, en el `select` le asignas un alias al campo que te genere conflicto

```
->select('Pacientes.ID', 'Medicos.ID as Medico_ID' 
         'Pacientes.nombre','Medicos.nombre as Medico_nombre'
         'Pacientes.apellidos', ''Medicos.apellidos as Medico_apellidos')
```

Y ya en la vista, usas el `alias` como si fuera otro campo normal.

```
@foreach ($MisPacientesHoy as $Paciente )

<div>{{ $Paciente->nombre." ".$Paciente->Medico_nombre}}</div>
```